# Android deep link in webview not opening the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deep-linking

i used webview to create app and implemented deep linking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ariagp.yazdarzan">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yazdarzan.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

now its asking for open link in my app, but it will not actually open with the app

**for example:** I click on the link shared in whatsApp, it will asking me for open in my app, i will choose the app but the link will open in whatsApp builtin browser

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ariagp.yazdarzan">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name="com.ariagp.yazdarzan.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />        
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yazdarzan.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post all of your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: No Unfortunately, the problem persists and opens with the built-in browsers...

Comment: so.. what about your MainActivity.java file?

Comment: I have some code for loading webview in it. But it is not related to this. Because now i created a completely empty project for testing and just changed the manifest file and again its not working...

Comment: i cant see any problem in this file, its working perfect on my wmulator:(.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. i hope somebody helps me